# Python Pandas group by one column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a data frame in Python as such;

```
varX varY varZ
01   A     34
01   B     26
02   A     18
02   B     50
```

How can I group this data frame by varX and take the sum of the third column(varZ) so that we can create a new data frame that looks like the following;

```
varX varZ
01   60
02   68
```

I already tried the following but it didn't work.

```
df_ = df.groupby(["varX"]).sum()
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: df.groupby(["varX"]).varZ.sum()

Answer (score 0):

Try do `sum` for `varZ` column:

```
print(df.groupby("varX")['varZ'].sum())
```

Exactly what you want do `as_index=False`:

```
print(df.groupby("varX",as_index=False)['varZ'].sum())
```